# iOS , OBD2 dongle , BLE

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, dongle, can-bus

I'm developing an iOS app for OBD2 dongle using BLE, but i have trouble sending commands to the dongle (for instance the command 'O' opens communication channel between obd2 and my iOS app), could anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Your problem is unclear.  What is your *specific* problem?  Can you show the code you have tried and where it isn't working?

Comment: My problem is that i want to send commands to the dongle that i'm connected to but i don't know what services uuids it's broadcasting. for example if i want to know my car speed , i should send this command to car obd = 7DF 8 02 01 0D 00 00 00 00 00 00 (the "0D" key means that i want the car speed)

Comment: You need to refer to the documentation provided by the hardware vendor, or you might be able to work it out by scanning for all devices or using an app like LightBlue